# How to size the SWT Controls in Absolute layout

Tags: java, swt, css-position

I use SWT components in absolute layout like the following:

```
Label l = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
l.setText("my lable");
l.setLocation(30, 30);
l.setSize(200, 30);  // doesn't work
```

As appears, I cannot resize the SWT components when using absolute layout!